# No property 'add' found for type Entity using Spring Boot to insert data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to do a simple insertion of data into my database using Spring Boot but I ran into this error 'No property type 'add' found for type Calendar'.

Use case: I am trying to insert a calendar event into my database using the .save() function for Spring.

This is my model class:

```
@Entity(name = "calendar")
@Table(name = "TB_EVENT")
public class Calendar {

@Id
@JoinColumn(name = "EventID")
private int eventId;

@JoinColumn(name = "Privacy")
private String privacy;

@JoinColumn(name = "EventCode")
private String eventCode;

@JoinColumn(name = "Subject")
private String subject;
```

This is my service implementation class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CalendarClassServiceImpl implements CalendarService {
private final Logger logger = 
LogManager.getLogger(CalendarClassServiceImpl.class);

@Autowired
private CalendarRepository calendarRepository;

@Override
public void add(Calendar calendar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    logger.info("invoked insertevent function in calendarServiceImpl");
    calendarRepository.save(calendar);


}
```

This is my repository class:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import sg.gov.agc.iw.model.Calendar.Calendar;

public interface CalendarRepository extends CrudRepository<Calendar, String> 
{

public void add(Calendar calendar); }
```

I am not sure why it is throwing me the error 'No property type add found for Calendar'. I spent 1 hour trying to figure out why but came to no conclusion. Does anybody know which part of my code is wrong ? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you update complete error message with stack trace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the `add` method from the repository interface. Spring data is not able to parse it (hence the exception). Note that you are using `save` (and not `add`) in your service (which is good).

```
public interface CalendarRepository extends CrudRepository<Calendar, String> {

    // Don't define add here, you save instead.

}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I removed the add and the error is gone. Do I need to specify the save function in the repository ? For e.g. public void save(Calendar calendar) ??

Comment: No all crud operations are provided by when your extend Jpa responsibly, only custom method has to define in repertory

Comment: As @kj007 pointed out, all the methods defined by `CrudRepository` are implemented out of the box by Spring Data.